# Android- same GPS location repeating without updating

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I have tried to do my research about GPS issues before posting here. When I tested my code It repeats the same output over and over. The method `gpsStart()` is called on a timer. Fine and Coarse location permissions have been added to the manifest. The method `appendLog()` stores the output in a file.

```
public void gpsStart() {
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location changed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location
                // provider.
                appendLog("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLng: "
                        + location.getLongitude()+"\n");
                text3.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLng: "
                        + location.getLongitude());
            }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
    // updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting same problem at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers. Dharmendra you are correct, I did need to close the LocationListeners, however the answer to my question was much simpler. I needed to change the minimum time (the time the listener waits to get an answer) to a value above zero. The value I needed to change is shown in bold below (MINTIME).

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINTIME, 0, gpslocationListener);        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MINTIME, 0, networklocationListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must not call `gpsStart()` method in the timer. I am going to say how Location Listener works

> What is Location Listener?

Location Listener is the class which notify you when your current location will be change. For receive the location updates you will have to register LocationListener class using LocationManager class.

> When to register Location Listener?

It depends on the requirement of your application. For example if you want location listener for display current location on map then you should register Location Listener in `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method of the activity and unregister receiver in `onPause()` or `onStop()` method. If you want to receive the location even if your application is not running then you can use a service to receive location.

> How to Register/Unregister Location Listener?

To register the LocationListener you first need the instance of the LocationManager class which you can get using the context like

`LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

After then you will have to set the location provider. There are 2 types of providers which are often used.

1. GPS provider
2. Network Provider

Now to register the location receiver with this location provider there is a method `requestLocationUpdates` of LocationManager. In this method first argument is the provider name second argument is the minimum time for request location update. Third argument is the minimum distance to request for the location change.Last argument is for locationListener.
Here how you can use the method

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
```

To unRegister location updates you can use the below method

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)
```

**Note:** You are calling a method `gpsStart` in the timer as you have mentioned in your question so it is adding location listener each time when this method calls.So all the listeners are triggering you the new location so probably you are getting same location multiple times. Instead of it, you should call this method once when your activity starts and unRegister this locationListener when your activity finish.

Hopes you are getting. :D

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

Better you create a 2 listeners.1 for Gps and other for network.

the following are code samples

```
public class MyLocationListener extends LocationListener  
{
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
           {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location changed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location
                // provider.
                appendLog("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLng: "
                        + location.getLongitude()+"\n");
                text3.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLng: "
                        + location.getLongitude());
            }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    }

MyLocationListener gpsListener=new MyLocationListener();
MyLocationListener networkListener=new MyLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpslocationListener);    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networklocationListener);
```